# Security for message queue in ActiveMQ

Tags: passwords, authentication

I am using `ActiveMQ` and `WSO2` for my application. I need to protect my queue to restrict posting of messages by anonymous users(I need to protect my queue with some password). I know, there is a Authentication plug in available in `Apache ActiveMQ`. But I guess, it is for restricting access to admin console. Any examples would appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally, I got the solution after I tried for one week. [https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.1/html-single/Security_Guide/#FESBLDAPTutorial] in this link.